# new files appear on GitHub, but don't replace old ones

Tags: git, github

Essentially, I first rename a file from within my Ubuntu file navigation program (Nautilus). I then run `git add .` (I also tried `git add *`), then `git commit -m "blah`, then `git push`. The changes are pushed to the server successfully, but on the server, the newly named files are failing to *replace* the old ones; they appear side by side,which was not intended.

Thank for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `git add .` and `git add *`. But these two command would not add the removed file to index stage. If you type `git status`, you should see like this:

```
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   deleted:    README.md
```

And before `git commit`, you can use `git add -u`(which would stage removed or modified files, but no new files) after `git add .` or `git add *`. Or just use `git add -A` to stage all removed/modified files and new files.

Or you can do like what @Laurent said, use `git mv`. You even not need to do `git add`.

Answer (score 2):

In general, use `git mv` to move files within a git repository. For now, you can `git rm` the files that you no longer need.